# ghostpcl 9.53.2 linux version gives errors for PCL file; windows version does not for same file

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to use ghostPCL 9.53.2 (current version) to convert a small PCL file to PDF. The process is failing on Linux, but working on Windows (same rev application, same small PCL file.)

The command lines I am using are as follows (linux, windows respectively), assuming the input PCL file is called 1.pcl and the intended output file is called 1.pdf.

./gpcl6-9532-linux-x86_64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o 1.pdf 1.pcl

gpcl6win32 4 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o 1.pdf 1.pcl

On Windows (running GPCL6WIN32.EXE on Windows 7 32-bit), the conversion completes properly, resulting in a small PDF file that looks correct.

On Linux (running gpcl6-9532-linux-x86_64 on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04) the conversion stops prematurely with a couple of errors and a prompt (I presume are something found in the PCL file):

%%BoundingBox: 17 315 612 747

%%HiResBoundingBox: 17.999999 315.953990 611.279981 746.999977

End of page 1, press  to continue

The file comes from an old late 1980s-era electronic instrument that can print it's display screen to PCL (in lieu of a printer, I'm capturing the data and seeking to convert it to PDF.)

I do not see right now a way to attach the small PCL file to this posting.

Thank you for any advice,

Dave

Comment: I just tested the gpcl6-9532-linux-x86_64 binary with the PCL/PXL files included in the archive, and they all run to completion and produce a PDF. The "errors" you posted are not errors, they are output from the default bbox (bounding box) device. Can I suggest you double check the command line you used on Linux, *just* in case. And then open a bug (attaching the input file): https://bugs.ghostscript.com/ ?

Comment: I will do so...

Answer (score -1):

Do not use option "o" for specifying the output file, but instead "sOutputFile" :

```
./gpcl6xxx-yyyy -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -sOutputFile=my_pdf_file.pdf my_pcl_file.pcl
```